# Springboot application autoconfigure @SpringBootApplication error in vscode

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to spring-boot and decided to try out vscode as my editor [via this setup tutorial from Microsoft](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot).

I was able to get the basic application to run but I now have the following error. If I ignore the error, it still runs - but there is no actual problem that I can see since this is the boilerplate code from the tutorial.

Is this just a vscode thing? I had trouble using the built-in boot initializer extension vs the spring initializer website as well.

I haven't done code in a while and used to use eclipse, but wanted to try vscode. If vscode is known to be a buggy or problematic I'll go back to eclipse. Is there some additional setup for vscode and spring-boot I need to do be doing?

Also, not sure if this is related - but the MS doc above said to have maven preinstalled, but then it looks like the [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) is recommends installed its own version?

Screenshot:
[image: showing my editor and the problematic line]

Comment: I tried migrating to vscode as well, and have now used it for php, java, c#, angular. My initial issues with java and spring boot were to make sure that all the environment variables pointed to `java.home` in `settings.json` a bit of googling removed all the errors.

Comment: It tells you that `Application` is already defined. Do you have another class with name `Application` in the same package? Try renaming your main application class to `DemoApplication` for example to see if the problem persist.

Comment: Did you added plugin for this? and yes then which one? Because when i tried same thing earlier and face same issue. Because of spring boot come with some predefined dependent tool configuration which are not directly find out in VS code. You have to manage it manually.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel i installed what MS suggested and then some generic tools - are you saying that maybe they are conflicting and that is why they have the issue?

Comment: @yann39 this was the problem - the Application class existed in `...\main\...` and I created my new code udner `..\test\...` - I didn't have the other directory expanded in the IDE. When I started looking in explorer I saw the old one. I guess spring does not care where the files are (e.g., i had non-test things in test folder). If you post this as a full answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that `Application` is already defined.

Do you have another class with name `Application` in the same package ?

Try renaming your main application class to `DemoApplication` (for example) to see if the problem persists.

Spring does not care about the file path, as soon as they are in the same package, they will conflict if they have the same name. `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is a composition of `@Configuration`,  `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and especially `@ComponentScan` annotations, which means that Spring Boot will auto scan components in the current package and sub packages.

If needed you can define the packages to be scanned as annotation parameter, for example :

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.project.package1", "com.project.package2"})
```

You could also provide your own `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations instead, where you will be able to change default settings and define the packages to be scanned (you can here use  filters and regex if you need to be more specific, see [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)).